# Setting up etw logs in azure table with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Spent more than 4 hours trying to figure out why etw logs wont show up in my tables. I still am unable to figure out why my logs are not showing up in azure table.

**EDIT**
The service is hosted as cloud service.

Here is how my diagnostics xml looks like. This is auto generated by selecting options in visual studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <DiagnosticsConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <EtwProviders>
          <EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration provider="AzureEventSource">
            <Event id="1" eventDestination="Error" />
            <Event id="2" eventDestination="Warning" />
            <Event id="3" eventDestination="Debug" />
            <Event id="4" eventDestination="Performance" />
            <DefaultEvents eventDestination="Default" />
          </EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration>
        </EtwProviders>
        <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT2M" />
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount />
  </PublicConfig>
  <PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <StorageAccount endpoint="" />
  </PrivateConfig>
  <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
</DiagnosticsConfiguration>
```

This is how my class looks like

```
using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing;
namespace CommonUtils
    internal sealed class AzureEventSource : EventSource, ILogger
    {
        public AzureEventSource(Type owner) : base(owner.FullName)
        {
        }

        private bool IsInputInvalid(String message)
        {
            return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message);
        }

        public void Error(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            if (IsInputInvalid(message))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("message");
            }

            this.WriteEvent(1, string.Format(message, args));
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something simple.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you hosting your web app in an Azure VM? If yes, have you enabled Diagnostics in your Virtual Machine?

Comment: Added the edit. It is a cloud service. So technically it is on a VM. How do I turn on diagnostics on the VM? I followed this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/

Comment: did you follow this step in that article? "How to Enable Diagnostics in a Virtual Machine"

Comment: I did not because my web app is running as a worker role. I tried the example by just following the steps on "Worker Role", deploying it to a cloud service and it worked fine. However the worker role is not a asp.net application and hence I feel that is where I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource) in your above example.

You're missing EventSource Event attributes for your class and method respectively.

A simple hello world of eventsource looks like this.

```
[EventSource(Name = "HelloEventSource")]
internal sealed class HelloEventSource : EventSource
{
    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "Hello World! {0}")]
    public void HelloWorld(string name)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, name);
    }
}
```

You should fix the tracing part of your code and check the logs are getting generated locally on your machine/vm.
Sending the events via diagnostics pipeline of your choice comes next.